# Xcode 9 build issue with Date vs NSDate for NSManagedObject

Tags: xcode, date, core-data, nsmanagedobject, codegen

Xcode 9 generates different code for `Date` type attribute of the entity in simulator vs device. I have `codegen` feature under `Class` set to `category/extension` in coredata.

Until Xcode 8.3 (latest) it was all working fine (`NSDate` always). Below is the **auto generated code** by Xcode 9 (Swift 4) for the attribute -

**On Device**:-

```
@NSManaged public var requiredDate: Date?
```

AND,

**On Simulator**:-

```
@NSManaged public var requiredDate: NSDate?
```

[image]

Anyone encountered this problem? What is the best solution for a project with 50+ members to fix this until an Xcode update fix it (I hope there is an apple radar for this)?

Comment: Actually even in Swift 3 the recommended class (struct) is `Date`

Comment: I assume you are just commenting your observation, not suggesting or asking anything. Note, the code I pasted above is *auto generated* by Xcode since codegen setting is NOT "Manual/None". Updated my question language to be more clear.

Comment: I'm suggesting the compiler is not perfect, don't trust it blindly. For example even if you declare a Core Data attribute as non-optional the compiler generates optional properties regardless, and the compiler generates `NSNumber` for any numeric type although Swift `Int`, `Double`, `Bool` is perfectly valid, too.

Comment: Yeah, true. I don't know what is the best way to resolve this. Don't want to use "Manual/None" setting. And, if I use #if macro and handle this attribute differently on device vs simulator then I'm worried when Xcode will fix this in an update then the whole team + automation servers needs update Xcode all at almost same time. Treat it as major Xcode update. Not a good solution.

Comment: There is some **randomness** in this issue. Suddenly, the issue has disappeared automatically and `codegen` has settled on Date on both simulator and device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer this myself. These are my observations (so far) and potential solution.

This issue seems **RANDOM**. Suddenly, the issue has disappeared and `codegen` has finally settled on `Date` on both simulator and device.

However, I applied macro based solution (and now no longer needed) to solve it -

```
// Workaround for Xcode 9 bug. The autogenerated code for 'Date' type attribute is NSDate vs Date based on device vs simualtor.

// This macro condition should be removed once an Xcode update fixes this issue
#if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64))    // Simulator
    requiredDate <- (map["requiredDate"], NSDateTransform())    // milliseconds to NSDate
#else   // Device
    requiredDate <- (map["requiredDate"], DateTransform())    // milliseconds to Date
#endif
```

PS: I remember I tested it working at least on iPhone SE Simulator, iPhone 7 device

Comment: Please report this to Apple's bug reporter: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: As told in my answer this issue is strangely random. I came across this issue in our existing project after Xcode 9.0. I applied the workaround mentioned in this answer then it was all good for one day. Then suddenly, compiler again complained (build error) so I ended up removing the workaround, settling on `Date` for all. Never saw this issue again after that.

Comment: Yeah, where would we put this code, @Ashok? Thanks. This problem is utterly ridiculous. 3 Months and still not fixed.

Comment: I have this problem too, but it didn't magically go away for me. I've submitted a bug to Apple.

Comment: I ran into this with XCode 9.2 (9C40b), but ultimately just needed to run Clean to get rid of all the old generated code.